# Difference between furious/infuriated/enraged?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, difference

I called him something, so he started walking toward me, furious/infuriated/enraged.

Is there any difference between them? Can I use them all here? Which one of them would you use here to mean very angry?

Answer (score 1):

> Furious, Infuriated, Enraged

ALL of them mean VERY VERY angry and are mostly interchangeable.

According to Merriam-Webster:

> Definition of furious
>   - exhibiting or goaded by anger
>   - indicative of or proceeding from anger
>   - giving a stormy or turbulent appearance

You can see that "furious"mostly means "very angry". However, it also has some extra meanings. You can think of "Fast and **Furious**". "Furious" here doesn't mean "very angry" but rather something like "very noisy, rapid, etc"

"To infuriate" means to make someone **furious** (very angry) so "infuriated" means "made furious", which basically just means "furious"

"To enrage" means to make someone be filled with rage, which means to make then very angry. "Enraged", therefore, just means "filled with rage" or "very angry".
- marked by noise, excitement, activity, or rapidity

Answer (score 0):

*Infuriated* and *furious* share a root meaning - "furious" is an adjective, and the *state* of being angry, whereas "infuriate" is a verb, meaning *to cause someone to be angry*. "*Infuriated*", as well as being the past-tense, is also an adjective form describing someone's state *after* someone or something has made them angry.

Likewise "enraged" can be an adjective, the verb form being "enrage" (to cause rage).

Both carry similar weight of meaning, so take your pick. "Furious" is probably more natural in modern speech. "Rage" is a common suffix to modern problems (eg *Road Rage*), but "enraged" is not used so much.